# Error in converting jpg to gif using Image.Save

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, graphics, byte

What i am trying to do is to convert an image into a byte array and then write that byte array into a file. here's the code

```
public static byte[] Convert(Image img)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
            // or whatever output format you like
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Bitmap pic = new Bitmap("tulips.jpg");
        pictureBox1.Image = pic;
        byte[] img_array;
        img_array = Convert(pic);
        File.WriteAllBytes("test.txt", img_array);

    }
```

Now I have been successfully able to convert the image into byte array. I have checked the values in byte array by means of a breakpoint and all of them are valid.

However when I try to write the array into a file and then open the file all I see is garbage.

Am I missing something?

Comment: So you _can_ write the array to a file.

Comment: "test.txt" is a strange name for a GIF image. A doubleklick on this file will open Notepad, which doesn't know about images. Try "test.gif".

Comment: No, it's not a text file. What do you use to open it, NotePad?

Comment: @WinCoder - you wrote an image to it, so it's an image file.

Comment: but isn't an image file composed of bytes

Comment: @WinCoder: Every file is composed of bytes, but not all files are meant to be interpreted as text.

Comment: What application are you trying to open test.txt with?    And no an image file is not a text file.

Comment: hmmm.....wierd. When i examine the byte array there are just numbers, so why can't simple numbers be written to a text file.

Comment: Sure you can write numbers to a text file.  And when you open it in a text editor you are going to see garbage (most like the Unicode of the numbers).   Why do you refuse to save it with the proper gif file extension?

Comment: it seems my image concepts are really flawed. Can anybody please point me out some book where i can get more information on this topic ?

Comment: @WinCoder - maybe your concept of a *file* is flawed. Yes you write bytes and they are stored as such. But when you open the file as *text* Notepad interprets those bytes as characters, so a byte-value of 48 might become a character '0' (depending on encoding).

Comment: @WinCoder and to add to Hans Kesting's comment, if you ever plan to modify the image, you need to know that most image formats are constructed with two sections, the header, saying HOW to interpret the bytes that come after and then an array of bytes which represent the actual pixels. The header will contain width / height and usually how many bits are used per pixel and how they're distributed (like ARGB - 1 byte per channel or RGB - 565 bits per channel, etc...)

Comment: Thanks to both of you guys now i have a much better understanding. Additionally may i know from which book do you get this information so i can further study topics such as this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Bitmap` is an `Image`. Why do you convert it into a `byte` array when you can simply call `Save` (documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh.aspx))

```
Bitmap pic = new Bitmap("tulips.jpg");
pictureBox1.Image = pic;
pic.Save("test.gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
```

To manipulate the image, you will usually access the `pixel data` - what you have now contains the **file type header** as well as the pixels! See `Bitmap.LockBits` to manipulate the pixels (documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d.aspx))

Comment: thanks. May i know from which book do you get this information about what is a file and what are the components of an image, so i can further solidify my understanding.

Comment: Usually I use the internet, rarely books, MSDN, Wikipedia and Google will help you, check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_file_formats for more infos about file formats

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you are trying to open the file with an image viewer? The `.txt` extension would typically cause it to be opened with a text editor instead. Since the format of an image file is binary, it is to be expected that you would only see "garbage" when you render it as text. It would help if you use the correct extension, `.gif`, when saving the file.

```
File.WriteAllBytes("test.gif", img_array);
```

Comment: 10-to-1 odds this is the root problem.

Comment: i have delibrately made it a .txt since i wan't it to open with notepad. When i examine the byte array it just contains numbers. Why can't these numbers be simple written to a text file ?

Comment: @WinCoder You do know notepad cannot display an image.

Answer (score 1):

What did you expect to see? You're saving the byte array to a text file. When you open a text file that has image file bytes, there's no way you're going to get a good result.

Ensure that you're saving the file as the proper type, then see what happens.

Comment: i don't understand. when i check the byte array it simple has numbers, so why can it write numbers to a text file.

Comment: @WinCoder - Those are the actual bytes. When you write the bytes back out to a file, the file contains those bytes. If you want to convert the bytes to a string and then write that to the text file, that's different.